# Text background is a bit lighter than emacs' background color

Tags: faces, themes, colors

[image: screenshot]

*If you can't see the screenshot in full resolution, click [here](https://ptpb.pw/3HWC.png)*

So you may or may not see that the background color "behind" the text (including the linum) is lighter (`#20292D`) than the window's background color (`#20282C`).

Please note that the background color set in my theme is the latter, `#20282C`, as seen [here](https://github.com/tudurom/xresources-theme/blob/master/xresources-theme.el#L105).

My question is, what is causing the text to have a lighter background color and how can I make it to be the same as the window's color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your cursor on a character in the text, and hit `C-u C-x =`. That will tell you what face, if any, is used at that position.

Then click that face name in buffer `*Help*` (or use `M-x customize-face`) to look at the definition of that face. Probably it specifies a background, and that background color is similar to but not quite the same as the background color of the frame.

You can check the background color of the frame by `M-x pp-eval-expression RET (frame-parameters) RET` - look for `background-color`.

Use `M-x customize-face` to remove the background attribute from the face (or make it the same as the background of face `default`, which is used for the frame, including non-text areas).

Comment: With `C-u C-x =` I found out that the background color of the text is correct, while the color of the frame itself is a bit darker. After further investigation, I discovered that I am affected by [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239627/4745418). Thanks anyway

Comment: Interesting. I guess you can set the face to whatever color you want, but because of a GTK bug you cannot set the frame background to the same color.